# Only one thread is starting python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

```
def pingGetterLoop():
    while(1):
        pingGetter()

def mainLoop():
    root.mainloop()


print("thread two")
threadTwo = Thread(target = mainLoop())
print("thread one")
threadOne = Thread(target = pingGetterLoop())

threadOne.start()
threadTwo.start()
```

for some reason threadTwo never starts and the output is always threadOne but when I switch the positioning of threadTwo over threadOne then threadOne doesn't run. I suppose it is the way they are getting into queue but, I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you pass the functions to the threads. You call them instead of passing the callable. You can fix that by removing the brackets `()`:

```
print("thread two")
threadTwo = Thread(target=mainLoop)
print("thread one")
threadOne = Thread(target=pingGetterLoop)
```

As both functions contain a endless loop, you never get past calling the first one, which then loops forever.